# Why does my API call function fail when I use input of data frame column to create new column?

Tags: r, api, dataframe

My data frame has a bunch of API queries, each column being a search term and then the rows being time periods. So for example I might have column A and column B which have search terms "aaa" and "bbb" respectively. Then row 1 is the API call to search for either aaa or bbb (depending on column) for the period of 2014-2015, and row 2 would be the same but for 2013-2014, and so on.

I'd now like to generate a numerical column for each of these textual/url/api call columns returning the number of hits gotten from that particular api call. Basically now that I've made my grid of api calls and turned it into a data frame, I'd like to extend the data frame to record the hits for each query as well and store these hits in columns with related column names.

I tried the following:

```
df$sheSearch = getData(df$`she `)
```

Hoping I could do the usual df thing of making a new column by applying function to existing column. However this generates a seemingly unrelated error but one that only occurs when I try to call the function for elements of the data frame:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument
```

However if I first assign an individual element of the df to a variable and then call, I have no error:

```
 f = df$`she `[1]
> getData(f)
[1] 30864
```

Why is this happening and what's the workaround?

Here is the getData function (which I slightly modified from Rolf Fredheim's tutorial http://www.r-bloggers.com/web-scraping-working-with-apis/)

```
getData <- function(url){
  raw.data <- readLines(url, warn="F") 
  rd  <- fromJSON(raw.data)
  Sys.sleep(.2)
  rd[[1]]$meta$hits
}
```

Comment: Because "df$`and his daughter`" is of class `factor`. You can convert factor to character.

Comment: Your data is a `factor`, `print.factor` by default shows the possible `levels` or categories for the column, as in `factor(1:3)[1]`. You can either use `df$var <- as.character(df$var)` or add to your original `data.frame` construction like `data.frame(...,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: @thelatemail Your fix was correct, but my error with getData remains - in particular I am getting this error when I try to read the URL:df$sheSearch = getData(df$she) Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument

Comment: Try with `getData(df[["she "]])`.

Comment: Do you want to call getData with vector?

Comment: @bergant yes I do want to call getData for each value in each column of the data frame - I thought with data frames you could create a new column by feeding an existing column into a function even if the function only takes a single scalar argument, with the understanding that it would be applied row by row?

Comment: @Pascal that still produces the same error: df$sheSearch = getData(df[["she"]])
Error in readLines(url) : 'con' is not a connection

Comment: @sunny Yes, some functions in R are exactly as you described. But I think readLines can take only one string. Use `lapply` or some other function from *apply family with your function.